# Android studio problems login validation

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've been cracking my brain with this issues. I'm trying to validate if the an user credentials on a app connected to mysql are valid. The thing is that wherever I try to compare the result of the query with a string all I get is the else statement.

Here's the Fragment for the Login

```
package com.example.pablorjd.CheckThisOut;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etUsername;
    EditText etPassword;
    Button btnLogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    }

    public void onLogin(View view){
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type,username,password);

    }
}
```

I'm using a background class to make the connection to mysql

```
    package com.example.pablorjd.CheckThisOut;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://10.20.13.31/checkthisout/login.php";
        if (type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("true")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "If is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

I know the DB connections is working because I'm actually receiving the message that I set on the php file.
All I know is that for some reason the if statement is not working for this.

please if someone could shed a light for me that'd be great.

Comment: Use the debugger and some breakpoints in doInBackground() to see the value of the String before returning.
Either it returns null or something unexpected as "true " which of course is not equal to "true".
However you should probably use http codes in the response instead reading the response like this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually know that the string is false or true depending on the user and password used in the login form. I know this because whatever I do the else statement kicks in showing in the toast false or true.

Comment: So, I've been tinkering with this for a while. Using debugger I actually validated that the variable is indeed equal to what I'm comparing it to. For some reason it just doesn't enters the if. Could this be some sort of bug in Android studio? I'm using version 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

OK so, for some reason, the validation just wouldn't take the string comparison and instead jumped to the else statement showing in this case a Toast. What I had to do was to modify the string given to me by the php file so it would be just a number (0 or 1 in this case). then I parsed the string into an int and the if worked like a charm.

This is the resulting code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(result.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));

        if (val == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Login exitoso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Login erroneo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I still don't know why the if statement wouldn't work with strings.